# Can OTG HUB charge with connected charger more than 0.5A?

Tags: usb-on-the-go

I saw a video somewhere where man says that OTG HUB charges only 0.5A. Is there any superior OTG HUB which can charge more than 0.5A?

Comment: Use an active hub with own power supply. The 0.5A come from the fact that a micro USB OTG port only provides this much of power. As power can not be taken from the air the hub is limited to this amount. Using a phone with USB-C port may also an option if the phone supports USB power delivery. AFAIK in this case the hub could ask the phone if it provides more than the 0.5A.

Comment: depends on protocol of charged device, not charging device. you can connect external charger https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/177788

Comment: @Robert What do you, mean "Use active hub with own power supply"? I already have USB HUB with power supply but I think it charges 0.5A when power supply is connected, because when connected my tablet to USB HUB, it discharges when screen is on.

Comment: The hub only powers the USB client devices connected to the hub, not the tablet (sub master). This is the way defined by the USB spec. Some devices may violate the spec (power also on uplink), but of course they don't advertise this and I am not sure if the tablet would accept the power this way. A powering hub is only defined in the USB-C standard (and this does not work with adapters to micro-usb!).

Comment: @Robert So every device that supports USB-PD can be using OTG and be charging simultaneusly at least at 0.5A?

Comment: I am not sure, but at least charging via USB PD have to be supported by the phone for that. I don't think that all devices can do so.

Comment: It's strange how difficult is to find information about some things. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multifunctional USB OTG Host Hub Adapter Cable is compatible with all tablets and cellphones with OTG function. While it is promoted to OTG mode and charging mode can work simultaneously, in fact this is not possible (except for some listed devices)

[image: OTG Charge HUB]

Comment: Do you mean, I can't charge, even with 0.5A on any device which supports OTG?

Comment: If it's only for some devices, can I test my device using Active USB HUB with OTG adapter and data transfer/charging cable connected to tablet? If yes, my device isn't charging in that way, so it isn't supported?

Comment: No you can't charge at all (@Robert already stated)

Comment: Thank you for stopping of buying potentially useless thing. Do you know any of these lists? I'm not able to find any.