# Need Help Making 7" Monitor Display Android Screen

Tags: screen, hdmi, external-display

I got a 7 inch ultra thin TFT LCD Color Monitor that has HDMI, AV, VGA, and is DC12 volt - USB 5 Volt by TOGUARD D701.
I want to use it in my car with a android device (phone or tablet) to display things like GPS or music.

So far I can not get any android device (only phones so far) to display. I have also tried an old iPhone 5s and an iPod that is 5 years old with HDMI adapters for both apple and android products.

I can't seem to get anything to display onto the dumb monitor. (Dumb meaning no OS to it besides the device trying to connect).

What do I need or am I doing wrong? I need to set this monitor up so my father can plug his phone in and have a GPS he can see. The monitor is brand new and can connect to an Xbox one. So why won't an any android phone display when connected. The phones support MHL HDMI. Do I need a different type of supported HDMI connection?

Comment: MHL needs to be supported by both devices. As this display does not seem to support it you need an MHL to HDMI converter. In the end the combination of smartphone, adapter and display is not very portable. Wouldn't it be easier to use a 7" phablet?

Comment: while external monitor should work on every MHL device with proper cables, most devices can't be charged simultaneously https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/34741 
it's worth mention that charging with these cheap otg charge hubs didn't work on any of my devices https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220032 make some tests before buying phone