# Touch screen doesn't work inside TWRP on Xiaomi Redmi 9C

Tags: twrp, xiaomi, touchscreen, redmi

I have a Xiaomi Redmi 9C on which I try to install a new ROM. My problem is that when I launch `fastboot reboot`, it tries to reboot, I see Redmi displayed, but it keeps rebooting.

So once I switch to bootloader, I run `fastboot reboot recovery`,
I get to TWRP (3.5.2), but my touch screen doesn't work, I can't do anything. When the screen turns off, I can't even swipe to unlock it.

I also used Orangefox to see if it works better, no, I have the same problem. The recovery launches well but I can't do anything. The touch screen doesn't react.

What is the possible cause and how to fix it?

Comment: either use [adb](https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html) commands or connect [mouse](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220038)

Answer (score -1):

We are the same, I also have a Redmi 9c, I just waited 123 hours before unlocking the bootloader. What I can tell you is that you did wrong. You used TWRP on Redmi 9c even though it is not yet supported by TWRP.

The only supported models on Redmi are 1 to 7 while Redmi 9c is not yet. So that's the reason why your screen doesn't work. I have sent a message to TWRP members to support our Redmi 9c devices.

The solution is to format it, there are many software available so that you can use it again.